# Jenkins job dsl to configure server,nodes, plugins, etc

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I use Jenkinsfiles/multibranch pipelines.

I use the job dsl to create those multibranch pipelines.

So at this point my job config is totally codified.

But config for the Jenkins master itself is still manual. Can the jobs dsl do stuff like install and configure plugins, configure security settings, and create and configure node settings too?

Comment: Sounds similar to [JEP-201](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jep/blob/master/jep/201/README.adoc) and [JENKINS-31094](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31094).

Comment: cool did not know about that. I didnt find that info googling and seems like im not the only one wondering if the dsl is capable of this. But looks like "configuration-as-code-plugin" is exactly what i want, it can even create the initial seed jobs. Its super beta right now but at least its an official effort- thats the answer to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent for system configuration (yet) that is comparable to the Job DSL or Jenkins Pipelines `Jenkinsfile`. There are a few recent initiatives to change this:

- [jenkinsci/system-config-dsl-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/system-config-dsl-plugin) - experimental (and looks to be unmaintained) plugin
- [JENKINS-31094](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31094) - *"Proposal: Jenkins Configuration DSL"*
- [JEP-201 (Jenkins Enhancement Proposal) - *Jenkins Configuration as Code*](http://adfe51ad87ac1870affbaf0d0ecbcc9f8418c41a)

In the meantime, one of the ways you could accomplish this is by using the [Groovy post-initialization scripts support](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post-initialization+script). Those Groovy scripts run after initialization so you can "converge" an instance if the scripts are written in such a way. The Groovy scripting feature is also leveraged by some of the existing configuration management tools, such as the [Chef cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins/blob/master/libraries/credentials.rb).